# Does play sends csrf header in response or does it expect csrf token in requests

Tags: playframework-2.6

My application is not working due to `csrf` error. I am getting `403` response. All I have understood so far is that when I send a POST message (form), `Play` expects `CSRF Token`. But I am unable to find out from where this token comes.

Is `Play` suppose to send this token first to a client and the client is suppose to return it in every request? What is the Header which carries this token? Is It `csrfToken` or `Csrf-Token`?

I checked the `200 OK` response of the 1st request. I didnt see any `csrf` token.

Comment: I tried adding the following two configurations in `application.conf` but Play still is not sending CSRF token. `play.filters.csrf.cookie.name = "CSRF-Token"` and `play.filters.csrf.header.name = "X-CSRF-Token"`. I don't see any `Set-Cookie: CSRF-Token` in responses from `Play`

Comment: answered at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49225275/how-play-sends-csrf-token. Do not see option to mark it duplicate!