# how Play sends CSRF token?

Tags: playframework-2.6

When my application retrieves `index.html` and other `js` and `css` files from the server, I do not see an `csrf` token in headers or cookies. How does `play` sends csrf token?

My UI is an `Angular` application being served from `play`. From the documents, I read about `csrf` token that

`This token gets placed either in the query string or body of every form submitted, and also gets placed in the user’s session`

The documentation also says that

`To ensure that a CSRF token is available to be rendered in forms, and sent back to the client, the global filter will generate a new token for all`GET`requests that accept HTML, if a token isn’t already available in the incoming request.` - But I don't see this token in response to my initial `GET` request.

As my UI (and thus form) is not a play UI, I cannot use `play`'s annotation to put `csrf` token in the form. I would like that when the homepage is delivered, play sends the `csrf` token which `Angular` application can store and use later.

Following are the headers I see on browser's developer console.

Response headers

```
Content-Length      1421
Content-Type        text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date        Sun, 11 Mar 2018 21:23:52 GMT
Referrer-Policy     origin-when-cross-origin, strict-origin-when-cross-origin
X-Content-Type-Options      nosniff
X-Frame-Options     DENY
X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies       master-only
X-XSS-Protection        1; mode=block
```

Request headers (600 B)

```
Accept      text/html,application/xhtml+xm…plication/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
    Accept-Encoding     gzip, deflate
    Accept-Language     en-US,en;q=0.5
    Connection      keep-alive
    Cookie      PLAY_SESSION=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1N…AR2uh5KwKBhqKxQQT1wWPWC2yPyCM
    Host        localhost:9000
    Upgrade-Insecure-Requests       1
    User-Agent      Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; …) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/58.0
```

The `Action` in play which servers the homepage is

```
def index =
    Action { implicit request =>
      val Token(name, value) = CSRF.getToken.get
      println(s"Token name ${name}, value ${value}")
      Ok(views.html.index("Your new application is ready."))
    }
```

I can see (print) the token name and value but I am not sure if it is being sent in the `Ok` response.

Comment: your code `val Token(name, value) = CSRF.getToken.get` seems to apply to play forms, not ajax responses. Did you find a way to implement CSRF in play/angular?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a partial answer. The 3 `csrf` configurations of interest in `play` are `token`, `cookie` and `header` names

if none of the `token`, `cookie` and `header` of `csrf` properties are configured then the default values are `csrfToken` for token name), nothing gets configured for cookie and `Csrf-Token` for `header`

When `token` name is configured then `play` seem to send a `PLAY_SESSION` cookie. Eg `token.name = "CJCsrfToken"`. In this case, the name of the token is `CJCsrfToken` instead of `csrfToken`. However, I couldn't find how `csrfToken` gets sent and how to retrieve it in the client. I have an `Angular5` client and I couldn't get it to pass `csrf` when only `token.name` was configured in `play`.

If `cookie` name is configured, Play will store the `csrf` token in a cookie with the given name, instead of in the session. I suppose we should configure either `token.name` or `cookie.name`. Eg  `cookie.name = "CJCsrfCookie"`  means you should see a cookie with name `CJCsrfCookie`

Now if only cookie.name is configured but no header name is configured then Play expects that requests from client will contain the `csrf` token in header `Csrf-Token` (the default header name)

The code in `Angular` to accept the cookie and return header was

```
HttpClientXsrfModule.withOptions({ cookieName: 'CJCsrfCookie', headerName: 'Csrf-Token' }),
```

If you do not want to use default header name, configure the new name in `header.name`. This would be the name of the header to accept CSRF tokens from.
eg `header.name = "CJCsrfHeader"`

The code in `Angular` to accept the cookie and return header was

```
HttpClientXsrfModule.withOptions({ cookieName: 'CJCsrfCookie', headerName: 'CJCsrfHeader' }),
```

Note that for the Angular part, the url has to be relative. See this [angular4 httpclient csrf does not send x-xsrf-token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46040922/angular4-httpclient-csrf-does-not-send-x-xsrf-token) has

Comment: were you able to read the cookie in angular? It seems play CORS filter sets the cookie as HttpOnly.